# Copying data from datatable to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, copy

I want to copy data from a `DataTable` to a SQL Server table; how can I achieve it please help.

Comment: Or this [ADO.NET Tutorial at C# Station](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy [data from a DataTable to a SQLServer Database using SQLServer Management Objects and SqlBulkCopy.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataTableToDataBase.aspx)

You can also try [SqlDataAdapter to Update the data into the database.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308507)

Comment: thanks, can you tell me any link or smoothing else from where i can get know something about it.